# What does the preposition "to" in "he jumped to his feet" mean?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Normally, we say "**he stood on his feet**" (his feet supported him)

Sometimes, people say "**jump or stand to one's feet**".

I couldn't see the usage or meaning of "**to**" in this context in any dictionary.

What does the preposition "**to**" in "**he jumped/stood to his feet**" mean?

Comment: There is little point in asking what a certain preposition "means" in a particular construction. Prepositions are among the most idiosyncratic parts of different languages, and you just need to learn which is used in which ways - "meaning" barely enters into it.

Answer (score 3):

What you're missing is not a special definition of "to" but of the entire phrase "[to one's feet]." It is in fact in [this Merriam-Webster entry for *foot*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foot):

> **to one's feet**
> : to a standing position
> // *brought the crowd to its feet*

Using this with "jump" just communicates the sudden motion. It wouldn't really be used idiomatically with "stand," though maybe some other verbs: "He rose to his feet," "He leaped to his feet," "He teetered unsteadily to his feet."

Answer (score 3):

**Stand to one's feet** is not idiomatic in British English (though apparently it is in American).

We say **getting / jumping / leaping / springing to one's feet**, meaning that the person is rising (very eagerly, in the case of the last three) so that they end up on their feet. **To** is used in its normal sense, as in 'climb to the top'. We can speak of **falling to one's knees** as well - lowering oneself into a kneeling position.

Comment: I disagree that "stand to one's feet" is not idiomatic: https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22stood+to+his+feet%22

Comment: @stangdon - In that case it must be an American usage - it's quite unknown to me. The quoted books appear to be American.

Comment: I was inspired to do a little more research.  It does appear that "stand to one's feet" is both primarily American and recent: it started to gain traction in American English in the 1970s but didn't really take off until the 1990s, whereas in British English it didn't take off until the 2000s.   https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stood+to+his+feet%3Aeng_us_2019%2Cstood+to+his+feet%3Aeng_gb_2019&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstood%20to%20his%20feet%3Aeng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstood%20to%20his%20feet%3Aeng_gb_2019%3B%2Cc0

Comment: As Andy B mentions in his answer, *to one's feet* already implies a final, standing position.  *Standing to one's feet* is a bit like *Sitting into a sitting position.*

Comment: It's true that "*stood* to his feet" is much less common than *got*, *rose*, *sprang*, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess, but I think it must've been:

> He jumped to stand on his feet

We have, since, abbreviated it to:

> He jumped to his feet